# How to update Array v-model with custom emit event for multiple checkboxes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I know you can assign an array as a v-model for multiple checkboxes and the input event will automatically update the v-model array adding or removing the chekbox value. My question is how can I do that with a custom `$emit`. If I emit the input event itself it doesn't work, it just assigns my v-model the PointerEvent object, I need it to add/remove the event target value.

I have something like this, a main component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <helper-switch :name="email" v-model="fields"></helper-switch>
        <helper-switch :name="phone" v-model="fields"></helper-switch>
        <div>
            {{ fields }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import helperSwitch from './input/HelperSiwtch.vue'
export default {
    components:{
        helperSwitch,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            fields:[]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And another component `helper-switch`, which contains two checkboxes

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label for="c1">Field</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1" v-model="fieldBool" @click="e => updateFields(e)" />
    <label for="c2">Required</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c2" v-model="requiredBool" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    updateFields(e) {
      this.$emit("input", e);
    },
  },
  props: {
    name: String,
    value: Array
  },
  data() {
    return {
      fieldBool: false,
      requiredBool: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

What I need to do is emit an input event from the `helper-switch`, which will dynamically add or remove a custom object in my `fields` data from the main component

Comment: What is the expected value of `helper-switch` when the checkbox is checked/unchecked? Are you expecting it to add/remove an array element from `fields` in the parent?

Comment: I think `e => updateFields(e)` is the problem. Try `@click="updateFields($event.target)"` This should give you information about your clicked input.